# Setting local variable through repeater and anchor or label

Tags: asp.net, datareader

I have a repeater which fetches data from a database and shows some labels (or anchors). I have a local variable on this class which must be updated by the value retrieved from database. To cut the matter short, there is a list of labels shown by repeater, when user clicks one of them, a variable on the form (which is called swfFilename) is fetched and is passed to the flash object on the page. My code is shown below:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <a onclick="<%#swfFileName = DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MediaFile").ToString() %>" href="Index.aspx"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %></a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

My code is not working properly and it seems that it is not assigning new value to the variable. Any help to assign the fetched value to the `swfFilename`? BTW, Index.aspx is the same page that we are currently over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would creating a javascript function ousdide of the repeater that takes the mediaFile string as a parameter and then manipulates the swf object work?

So something along these lines ...

```
<script>
    function manipulateFlash(mediaFile) {
        // set do stuff to flash object
        // assign mediaFile to flash object etc.
    }
</script>

<asp:Repeater>
    ...
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a onclick="manipulateFlash('<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MediaFile").ToString() %>')" href="Index.aspx"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Text") %></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    ...
</asp:Repeater>
```